# What does Dark magic do?

Tags: infinity-blade

The Dark Mech items have dark magic bonuses (looks like a black circle or teardrop in their stats), but I can't tell what the magic actually does when activated in battle. If it does extra damage, how much?

Answer (score 2):

Dark Magic is no different from the other types of magic spells in Infinity Blade (fire, ice, light, etc.). Dark Magic is just another school of magic that an enemy can be weak to, or have protection against.

Answer (score 0):

it slowly takes down their health!